# cpan vs -MCPAN - Perl

Tags: windows, perl, cpan, cpanm

I'm currently running `bash` via Cygwin on Windows, and I've come across two different ways to install a Perl module

```
cpan Name::Module
```

and

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell

install Name::Module
```

What's the difference between these two methods, and do they offer any advantages or disadvantages over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cpan` installs for the `perl` in the shebang (`#!`) line of the `cpan` file.

When someone has more than one `perl` installed on a machine, they sometimes run the wrong copy of `cpan`, and thus end up installing modules for the wrong instance of `perl`.

One solution to that would be to specify the full path to the correct `cpan` file.

`perl -MCPAN -e shell` is the other solution. It allows you to explicitly specify the install of `perl` for which you want the modules to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

cpan on Windows just calls `App::Cpan->run( @ARGV )`, which should give you the same shell as the other command, maybe with other settings active. But I think it's the same. So you could use both. I prefer just `cpan` and then do `install Name::Module`, since I tend to look if it's installed before and which version in the cpan shell beforehand.